# Why the div doesn't appear where I right-click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, mouse

Could you please tell me why the div not appearing right where I click? It appears on top-left only.

CSS:

```
#palette {
    display: none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="palette"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById('palette').setAttribute('left', ev.pageX);
  document.getElementById('palette').setAttribute('top', ev.pageY);
  document.getElementById('palette').setAttribute('position', 'absolute');
  document.getElementById('palette').style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}, false);
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0rL9neeL/

EDIT: Sorry, seems like I haven't explained an issue: Yes, it is the right click. That's where the `div` should appear.

Comment: is  this really off-topic?

Comment: I've posted my answer to your question. You should use clientX and clientY to get mouse coordinate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the coordinates using `ev.clientX`, `ev.clientY` for example(which returns the coordinates relative to the viewport in CSS pixels), and then just set the styles with javascript. You can do it this way:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('palette');

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var x = ev.clientX;
  var y = ev.clientY;
  element.style.display = 'block';
  element.style.left = x + "px";
  element.style.top = y + "px";

  return false;
}, false);
```

```css
#palette {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette"></div>
```

The problem with your code was that you were using `setAttribute` which sets atributtes to DOM elements, and not inline CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting styling as attribute while in fact you should set it on the  style object

```js
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var style = {
    left: ev.pageX + 'px',
    top: ev.pageY + 'px',
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'block'
  }
  Object.assign(document.getElementById('palette').style, style)

  return false;
}, false);
```

```css
#palette {
  display: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were attempting to set the `left`, `top`, `position` and `display` properties of the element itself, rather than the `style` property (which returns an object) of the element. Also, you need to append your unit of measurement (pixels in this case) on to the value for the `left` and `top` properties.

```js
window.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  // Just get a reference to the DOM element once:
  var pal = document.getElementById('palette');
  
  // Every DOM element has a style property, which exposes
  // a style object that, itself, exposes the various CSS
  // properties. Also, remember, CSS requires units of measurement
  pal.style.display = 'block';
  pal.style.position = 'absolute';
  pal.style.left = ev.pageX + "px";
  pal.style.top = ev.pageY + "px";

  // No need to return false here, that wasn't doing anything for you
  
});
```

```css
#palette {
    display:none;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="palette"></div>
```

Comment: @Endless Is it? I guess you aren't the detail oriented type. Is it like yours? It's only like lonut because I edited his answer. And, my answer explains something that no one else's does. Read it again.

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the window will display the red square on top-left. You've added event listener for context menu and that's the right-click.

I would suggest trying `ev.clientX` and `ev.clientY` to get the mouse coordinate.

https://jsfiddle.net/0rL9neeL/3/